# CSS formating table row and column width

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
     </tr>
...more rows.
```

The table will look like this

```
|col1|col2|
|col1|col2|
|col1|col2|
|col1|col2|
```

Where all columns follow a vertical line. I dont want row X to follow the same vertical lines as the rest of the table, so it should look something like this

```
|col1|col2|
|col1|col2|
|this row should not follow the same vertical lines|col2|
|col1|col2|
```

is there someway i can do this with CSS?

Comment: No, that's the purpose of table. Use different table for that particular line or put it in separate div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to either *not*  use table tags at all in HTML or to use them, but apply `display: block` to all `table`, `tr` and `td` elements and fixed `width` to all those elements. (which, however, makes the use of the table tags meaningless)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `table` in that case, you can mock table look and feel using `flex or float`, have a look at the below working snippet(using bootstrap 4), hope it helps :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border col-auto">col1</div>
    <div class="col border col-auto">col2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border col-auto">col1</div>
    <div class="col border col-auto">col2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border col-auto">this row should not follow the same vertical lines</div>
    <div class="col border col-auto">col2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border col-auto">col1</div>
    <div class="col border col-auto">col2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you alternative solution, but it does not solve my problem as i have to use existing html structure.